# Difference between creating redis cache using jedis client and by using azure management API(Azure object)

Tags: java, azure, azure-redis-cache, azure-management-api

I am having a doubt that what could be the difference between creating azure redis cache using jedin client vs creating it using resource management API(Azure object). How can we effectively manage the redis cache using management API? And if we are using the mamagement API, then how it should be created and maintained in the whole application such as the Azure object gets created only once and is accessed over the whole application when required. I am using Java/Maven project. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience, [Azure Management API for Redis Cache](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/redis-java-manage-cache) and Jedis client are totally different SDKs.

Azure Redis Cache is created in the form of resource on azure, including `Dns name`,`Subscription`,`Resource group`,`Location`,`Pricing tier` and `Virtual Network` etc. [Azure Management API for Redis Cache](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/redis-java-manage-cache) is to manage these resources about Azure Redis Cache Service.  You could create a Redis Cache and get the hostname or get the access keys or delete these resources etc.It is `IaaS` level thing.

On the other side, Jedis client is just one of the [recommanded clients](https://redis.io/clients) for Redis Cache .It is to use it ,not manage it. For example ,you could connect to the cache or add something to the cache and retrieve it etc. But you cannot modify the resource group or location etc. via Jedis client. It is `SaaS` level thing.

Any concern , please let me know.

Comment: Thank you @Jay Gong got it.